# Sharing 2 usb devices, sound and monitor between mac mini and PC

Tags: kvm-switch

I recently bought Aten Technologies CS692 2-Port USB HD Video/Audio KVM Switch and installed it to my PC and mac combination, however I were using a mouse/keyboard combo and the KVM switch had separate mouse and keyboard usb port so only keyboard was working...

So I bought a new mouse, a wired one! I plugged it in and it started working, however the mouse is not detected by my computer as the mouse it is([razer deathadder 3500](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-mice/razer-deathadder-black)) but as a generic mouse, so I figured the KVM switch was taking the mouse and keyboard input and rehandling it to the computer acting as a keyboard/mouse combo so the mouse driver couldn't be used, but I need it to work

So what I am looking for is a KVM switch that doesn't emulate to be a mouse/keyboard but just forwards the USB device to the computer that it's used on, is there any of those in the market or am I stuck with a switch that simulated mouse/keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, a machine will detect the finer points of devices connected to a KVM when the machine is rebooted while it's the active machine on the KVM. Give that a try and see if the devices are emulated or are discovered as what they actually are.

To cover bases, make sure that you have drivers installed for the mouse and the keyboard, if that applies.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like at least my KVM switch isn't giving the PC any details, because after full reboot(completely shut power) and rebooting the driver software(razer synapse 2.0) isn't finding the mouse til I plug it in without KVM switch in between.. :/

Comment: Could you share the manufacturer and model of the switch?

Comment: Its already on the first post: CS692 2-Port USB HD Video/Audio KVM Switch

Comment: Ah, pardon me. I didn't see that.  
  
From [this page](http://www.aten.com/products/KVM-Switches/Cable-KVM-Switches/2-Port-USB-HD-AudioVideo-KVM-Switch~CS692.html): To use the USB 2.0 mouse port as a USB hub, you must first disable mouse emulation mode.  
  
Mouse emulation mode sounds like something you want enabled. Check to see if it is?

Comment: Holy moly! You just saved me from buying another KVM switch, let me donate you some dogecoins?

Comment: Happy to help! Sure, if it's not against the rules: D6JXjtbc3LQKjT9LvRFwQu1pXnV42Lp6XL